# GCPへのovfファイルのimportについて

Tags: google-cloud

#### やりたいこと

OVFファイルをGCPにVMデプロイしたい

#### google clould shellに投入したコマンド

```
gcloud compute instances import cml2-test2 \
--source-uri=gs://test0roiuegej/cml2_test.ovf
--os=centos-7 \
--zone=asia-northeast1-c
```

#### 出力されたエラー

```
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_ovf_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) build dcf305d5-f13f-49ec-9d89-6c8489881b53 completed with status "FAILURE"
-bash: -os=centos-7: command not found
```

#### エラーについて

osのエラーについては他のブログやstackoverflowなどでも指定については誤っていないと思いますが、上記エラーが出力されてしまいます。
エラーの原因や解消法などご教示頂けますと幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: @cubick様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
--source-uriの末尾に/を補足しましたが、新しいエラーが出力されました。
有料枠のアカウントなのでquotaなどは特に制限されていません。
もし何か解決策などわかりましたらご教示頂けますと幸いです。


新しいエラーについて
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.import) FAILED_PRECONDITION: generic::failed_precondition: no concurrent builds quota available to create builds

Answer (score 0):

"`--os=centos-7` コマンドが見つからない" というエラーになっているので、ここから別のコマンドを実行したかのようになっています。
よく見ると `--source-uri` パラメータを指定している行の末尾に `\` が足りていないのが原因だと思います。

**修正後の実行例:**

```
gcloud compute instances import cml2-test2 \
--source-uri=gs://test0roiuegej/cml2_test.ovf \
--os=centos-7 \
--zone=asia-northeast1-c
```